# Visual Studio Android emulator won't open after updating VS

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

Recently updated VS to the newer version VS 2015 Community Edition from the pre release 2015 version.

Whenever I try to start the android emulator (tools>Visual Studio Emulator for Android) it throws an error instantly:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Visual Studio.Telemetry, Version = 14.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have tried to 'repair' visual studio and also the emulator itself in Programs and features.

Does anyone know how to fix this or is having the same issue?

Comment: You need to install build tools.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you don't have a version of the emulator that matches with a version of Visual Studio. Do you have RTM Visual Studio with an older version of the emulator? You can check by going to Add/Remove programs and verifying that:

1. Microsoft Visual Studio is version 14.0.23107.10 or greater
2. Microsoft Visual Studio Emulator for Android is version 1.0.50715.4 or greater

If not, you should uninstall the emulator and update it to the RTM version (the version number above or later).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the latest version of Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 (Update 3).

It turned out that I had to remove an old version of the emulator and then install the new version.

Although the documentation tells that the Visual Studio Emulator for Android will be installed with the Visual Studio Setup, I could not find any entry in the setup for the Android Emulator and changing or repairing Visual Studio setup did not help.

Thanks to @John Kemnetz answer I found out that an old version of the Android emulator was installed. Maybe this prevented Visual Studio setup to install the right version?

I uninstalled the old Android emulator from Control Panel => Programs and Features.

Next I downloaded the new Android emulator from [Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/) and now it starts OK.